# KeyError: 'input_1_ib-0' when i save my autoencoder model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, autoencoder

I get the error when save my Autoencoder model.
This is my [code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1W7VJUMwofzVpsfAC1V4gmFrD04S5TsvZ?usp=sharing). I have searched about this error but no solution help me solve this problem.

The error photo:
[image: The error photo].

Comment: Probably it is due to mixing keras and tesnorflow libraries. Use `from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam` and `from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model` instead  of keras ones.

Comment: thank you, i have solved it by fix the libraries like your instructor. It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it is due to mixing keras and tesnorflow libraries. Use `from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam` and `from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model` instead of keras ones.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Input, BatchNormalization, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Dropout, BatchNormalization
#from keras.models import Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model   # tensorflow.keras
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow 
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
#from keras.optimizers import Adam               
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam            # tensorflow.keras
```